# Norm on the space of finite signed Borel measures over a compact metric space

Tags: measure-theory

Let $S$ be a compact metric space. Let $\Delta^\ast(S)$ be the set of all finite signed Borel measures defined on $S$, and $\Delta(S)$ be the set of all Borel probability measures defined on $S$.

My question is, does there exist a norm (or topology) on $\Delta^\ast(S)$ that makes $\Delta^\ast(S)$ a Banach space (or locally convex space), and at the same time makes $\Delta(S)$ compact under the induced metric?

I know that the total variation norm makes $\Delta^\ast(S)$ a Banach space, however $\Delta(S)$ is not compact under the induced metric.

Comment: The weak-* topology (induced by the duality $\Delta^*(S) = C(S)^*$) does this, right?

Comment: There won't be a norm that does it, for any practical purposes.  There's a general principle that in order to construct two inequivalent complete norms on a vector space, you have to use the axiom of choice in an essential way, and so the new norm would be some horrible non-constructive monster that wouldn't likely be useful for anything.

Comment: Indeed, the weak-* topology will do. Thanks.

Comment: If you want a *complete* norm that makes $\Delta(S)$ compact, this is impossible unless $S$ is a finite set. The usual (total variation) unit ball of $\Delta^*(S)$ will be compact with respect to this norm, and so $\Delta^*(S)$ is a countable union of compact sets. In an infinite-dimensional normed space, compact sets have empty interior, so we have a contradiction with the Baire category theorem. (This comment can become an answer if you find it satisfactory.)